# I am good or I am well?

Tags: confusable

It is another confusing stuff for me, because I am getting answers after my question: how are you? 1. I am good. 2. I am well.

I tried to find which one is correct and I found that both are correct. For me it is a bit difficult to accept, until I will not get the reason why both answers are right.

I addition, **I'm good** sounds arrogant.
I believe in the people who are answering here.

Comment: They are synonyms in this case, since they both refer to health. https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/good

Comment: They're not always interchangeable. You can answer the question *"Do you need any help?"* with *"I'm good,"* but not with *"I'm well."*

Comment: I'm surprised you didn't ask about "I'm fine."

Comment: Thanks all for this great comments, especially to @PeterShor  (+1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Good (adjective)**: such as should be desired or approved, right, satisfactory; sound, unimpaired; not depressed or dejected.

**Well (adverb)**: free or recovered from illness; in a satisfactory state or position.

One can safely answer with either response and be grammatically correct, however the manner in which the question *(How are you?)* is asked must be kept in context.

If someone is clearly inquiring about your health, “I’m well,” is the normal response. If it is clear you are in good health, either responses are correct; although some people prefer to use “well” in more formal situations.

From [Merriam Webster, "Good vs Well"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/good)

> An old notion that it is wrong to say "I feel good" in reference to health still occasionally appears in print. The origins of this notion are obscure, but they seem to combine someone's idea that good should be reserved to describe virtue and uncertainty about whether an adverb or an adjective should follow feel. Today nearly everyone agrees that both good and well can be predicate adjectives after feel. Both are used to express good health, but good may connote good spirits in addition to good health.

Comment: Actually, "well" can also be an adjective  - and it *is* an adjective in "I'm well", "I feel well", "all is well", etc.

Comment: Thank you for nice explanation, now this topic is clear for me. +1 +accepted to this answer

Answer (score 1):

Both good and well are synonyms as adjectives implying healthy (in good health).

The latter (well) is more common.

Comment: In casual speech in 2017 Seattle, "I'm good" is much more common than "I'm well."

Comment: great for finding time and answering my questions +1. and
@mamster +1 for this statistics